# Call to member function getResourceId() on non object - Magento CE

Tags: php, magento

Firstly I'd like to apologise in advance if this is a stupid question - Although I have been writing PHP for the last 12 years, I work on bespoke applications and have only been using Magento for the last hour, so I'm clueless on its structure. If possible I'd like to avoid having to dig too much into Magento as the entire reason why I'm using Magento is to save time.

Anyway, the error:

```
Call to a member function getResourceId() on a non-object in /var/www/[site]/lib/Zend/Acl.php on line 1174
```

This error occurred after attempting to log in to the administration area immediately after install. The error is in the &_getRules method in lib/Zend/Acl.php.

So, I did a little digging and $resource (the variable it is attempting to call the  &_getRules method on) is actually an array - which I found odd as the this is the method definition:

```
protected function &_getRules(Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface $resource = null, Zend_Acl_Role_Interface $role = null, $create = false){
```

So, to verify that I wasn't actually losing my mind I wrote the following as the first line of the &_getRules method

```
if($resource!==null&&!$resource instanceof Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface){
    die('<pre>'.print_r($resource,1).' </pre>');
}
```

Which printed:

```
Array
(
    [G1] => Array
        (
            [instance] => Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Group Object
                (
                    [_roleId:protected] => G1
                )

            [parents] => Array
                (
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [U1] => Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_User Object
                        (
                            [_roleId:protected] => U1
                        )

                )

        )

    [U1] => Array
        (
            [instance] => bea423c23f6343e2b509fb192a00826f:3EOt7Vo0agtENPH8Wm73EOelgSDoDxYO
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [G1] => Ryan
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

So yeah, i guess my question comes in four parts:

1. Why doesn't this work out of the box?
2. Am I just being an idiot?
3. Why isn't PHP preventing this method from running considering the $resource variable is neither a Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface or null?
4. How do i fix it?

I should mention that this is a local test site, running on Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.4.9 (likely to be nginx in production though), PHP 5.5.12, Magento CE 1.9.0.2.

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

/***************************UPDATE***********************************/

Hi again everyone,

So I've noticed there is a pattern to how this problem/bug/whatever comes around. So, this is my admin url:

```
http://magento.example.local/admin_system/
```

If I go to this url, I am able to login and then this issue happens. At this point the url is now

```
http://magento.example.local/index.php/admin_system/[some_irrelevant_stuff]
```

So this is where it gets odd. If I then navigate to the original url I am once again redirected to the second url but the beginning of [some_irrelevant_stuff] is /index/denied/ (which I assume is relevant now haha).At this point I am provided the header of the Magento admin panel and I am able to logout.

OK so thats one part of the issue. If I then logout, or if I start my login process at /index.php/admin_system/ then I am able to log in and use the admin area as usual. So, the long and short of it is, I don't know what's going on but I'm hoping this extra info might get me more details.

Thanks for your time,

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I am genuinely surprised that nobody had an answer for this. Anyway, the following details are not so much an explanation as to what caused this issue, but a solution to stop it happening.

So, as you'll see from the edit of my question, I noticed that this seemed to have a bizarre connection to the URL and using different URLs to access the admin area (eg. /index.php/admin instead of /admin) caused different errrors. So for this reason, and because having index.php in all my admin area URLs, I took a look into rewriting the admin URLs. This is made available using this plugin: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-rewrites.html

If I'm not mistaken, I did not need to make any changes to the RewriteRule(s) that are set by default by magento so following the instructions on the plugin page above *should* work.

Either way, this appears to resolve the issue so I hope it helps someone having similar issues.